# How can I checkout specific folder and its content from a specific commit to external folder?

Tags: git, git-checkout

How do I retrieve a complete subfolder from a git (version 1.7.0.4) repository to a local folder WITHOUT checking out the whole repo in the first place?
I thought that this would be the solution:

`git --work-tree=/home/tmp/testcheckout checkout COMMITID -- images/*`

Example repo structure with some directories:

```
/git/project1/sourcecode  
/git/project1/images  
/git/project1/howto  
/git/project1/readme.txt
```

So the example command should checkout all files under `/git/project1/images` to `/home/tmp/testcheckout` that have been committed to that git repo up to commit COMMITID but it only checks out files that have been committed at that given COMMITID, ignoring all other files that have been committed before that.

**Problem:**
With the command above I only get the files from that subfolder that have been committed with the COMMITID.

**Question**:
What I want is to retrieve ALL files up to that COMMITID.
Any solution for this?

**Important**: I don't want to clone the whole repository (700GB) just to be able to retrieve 1GB of files later. So there must be a way to directly get the files out of a repo without cloning the whole repo.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question by giving examples of what the files paths are that you want to retrieve, and how you're not currently getting them? Also, what are you still using such an ancient version of Git? The latest stable version is 1.8.4.

Comment: Hi @Cupcake , I added a sample structure to make it clear what I need, but this clarifies my requirement

Comment: One thought is to use git-archive as follows: git archive -o dump.tgz COMMIT-ID images/* and then follow it up with a tar extraction into the work directory.

Comment: Sorry @PaulSweatte, but that question is only 6 months old, mine is over 3 years old!! Can you please remove your comment? I am going to update my question with a nice solution that works.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution to this. The solution has the following features:
- It does not checkout the WHOLE repo, it just checks out what you need (this comes in very handy if you have repos of 100GB and more)
- You create a new repo as target, so nothing gets changed in your original repo, nice ey?

**Solution**

```
git init /example/gittest
cd /example/gittest
git remote add -f origin /PATH/TO/SOURCE/REPO/.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo images >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Now it copies only the `images`folder from your original repo to this test repo. Then you can do with the data what you want.